# JSS Question about itemlink field type

Tags: jss

For a fresh installed Vue-JSS application, we have some examples in the `/Styleguide` route. One of them is  `SharedItemLink`.

From `/data/routes/styleguide`, we can see that `sharedItemlink` is a field of  `Styleguide-FieldUsage-ItemLink` component. From the definition in the `/sitecore/definitions/component` folder, I can see that `sharedItemLink` is of type `CommonFieldtypes.ItemLink`.

Now, I do a experiment about the children property of sharedItemlink: First, I add a new `Item 3`  under path `data\content\Styleguide\ItemLinkField\Item1`. under Item 3, I create a en.yml file which is very similar to en.yml under Item 1 (the name is slightly different)

In disconnected mode, I open `src\components\Styleguide\Styleguide-FieldUsage-ItemLink.vue` and add code below:

```
computed: {    
    sharedItemLink() {    
      console.log(this.fields.sharedItemLink.children);
      return this.fields.sharedItemLink;
    }
},
```

Then I start the jss app and observe the browser console, I can see the `children` property of sharedItemLink, it just point to the `Item 3` we created.

However, if you try connected or integration mode, then you can't find the `children` property of SharedLinkItem at all. It just disappears.

So here are my questions:

1. In the Styleguide Example, I can only use `children` property of SharedItemLink in the disconnect mode, what is the reason?
2. May I ask how we initialize and set properties for these `CommonFieldTypes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: these answers are relevant for Vue, React, and Angular - they are not specific to Vue.

**Question 1**

The `ItemLink` field type is synonymous with a `DropTree` field in Sitecore. I am able to reproduce the fact that you can add `children` to an item referenced by an `ItemLink` field in disconnected mode. And that the `children` items will even be imported into Sitecore. Unfortunately, however, that appears to be a mistake or oversight because Layout Service will not serialize the `children` by default.

When Layout Service is serializing the item that is referenced by the `ItemLink`/`DropTree` field, it does not serialize any children (or descendants) of the item. This is by design in order to prevent serializing deeply nested item trees (and thus leading to performance issues in Layout Service).

You can implement your own field serializer in order to serialize `ItemLink`/`DropTree` children by extending (or replacing) the `Sitecore.LayoutService.Serialization.FieldSerializers.InternalLinkFieldSerializer`. Then you will need to extend the `Sitecore.LayoutService.Serialization.Pipelines.GetFieldSerializer.GetInternalLinkFieldSerializer` to return your custom field serializer depending on whatever conditions you specify. Note: the `GetInternalLinkFieldSerializer` is shared amongst all Layout Service configurations, so it is recommended to scope your serializer appropriately.

Also, I'll make a note that we (the JSS team) should either document the non-usage of `ItemLink` children or implement more validation during the manifest process to prevent `ItemLink` children from appearing in the manifest and being imported.

**Question 2**

The manifest API documentation has information about `field` declarations for manifest definitions: https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/working-disconnected/manifest-api#field

Beyond that, the sample apps serve as reference implementations / examples for the various field types you can use in a JSS app. If you have specific questions about field type usage feel free to post questions here on Stack Exchange or on the Sitecore community Slack site, in the #JSS channel.